# Exponent location of second y axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

A minimum working example for using a second y-axis in pgfplots is the code below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis y line*=left]

\addplot[no marks, blue] {x^2};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis x line=none, axis y line*=right]

\addplot[no marks, red] {x^7};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

resulting in
[image: Resulting plot]

How can I change to location of the exponent of the second y-axis (`\cdot 10^4`) from left to right where it belongs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`. Instead of `current` you can use the version number of your `pgfplots` installation. Current pgfplots version is 1.13.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} %<-
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis y line*=left]

\addplot[no marks, blue] {x^2};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis x line=none, axis y line*=right]

\addplot[no marks, red] {x^7};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `every y tick scale label` style:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis y line*=left]

\addplot[no marks, blue] {x^2};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[scale only axis, axis x line=none, axis y line*=right,
every y tick scale label/.style={
at={
(rel axis cs:1,1)},
anchor=south east}]

\addplot[no marks, red] {x^7};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I would prefer the label to be anchored south west, but that is just a matter of taste...